Magnetic moment of two electrons
For two electrons in the sate with S=1 and Sz=0, do we have a magnetic moment? Because the spin on the z axis is zero, thus if we couple it with a magnetic field on the z-direction we get zero.

Depends on what you mean by "having a magnetic moment". Have you tried calculating the expectation value of the magnetic moment operator in that spin state? (Which is to say, have you calculated the expectation value of the three spin components of the electron in this state?)

No I haven not but what I meant by magnetic moment is the ability to interact with magnetic fields. If we place this system in a magnetic field along z would it be affected? I think no.

It is sufficient to apply an appropriately strong magnetic field to induce a magnetic field in any material. This means that no matter how strong the pairwise alignment of two electrons to each other is (in the context of the real situation with the magnetic dipoles of the atomic nucleus), ultimately a sufficiently strong external magnetic field moves the dipoles of the electrons in its direction.
The theoretical case of the interaction of the magnetic dipoles of two free electrons without taking into account the repulsive electric fields corresponds to that of two bar magnets with two possible arrangements in relation to each other. Firstly, in series (long bar magnet) or secondly, head-to-toe (strongly encapsulated magnetic field). In the first case, the alignment takes place directly in an external field. In the second case, a sufficiently strong external field disrupts the head-to-foot alignment and we reach case one. That's why I wrote in the first paragraph that any material becomes magnetic with enough effort.

Thanks for the response. But if we have a magnetic field along z, and the electrons have Sz=0, their interaction U= - μ.Β ~ Sz.B = 0. So it seems to me that there will be no interaction here. That was my question.

If you hold two bar magnets in a very strong magnetic field, a head-to-foot arrangement will change into an arrangement in which the bar magnets are lined up. Since the context of the atomic nucleus has to be taken into account for the electrons, a (stacked ) row arrangement will of course not occur for the electron  probability shape. Just remember that an external magnetic field always influences the orientation of the magnetic dipoles. This can be seen in the shift of the always occurring shift of spectral lines as a function of an external field.
